# Remove current filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I have a list of items wrapped in `div` that can either be filtered using drop down or input box. 
How do you remove the filter from input box before filtering using the drop down? It only affect when filtered via `input` first then `drop-down`. It works the other way around.

I have an input box that filters the `div` with the following:

```
$("#dirSearchKey").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
$("#searchBlock div[class^=filterDiv]").each(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
});
});
```

The filter is cleared when user manually deletes the input box value. I found out I can't trigger a `delete` or `backspace` key. I tried removing the last character as suggested on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244677/trigger-backspace-key-in-jquery/9244690) but it didn't work.

I'm using below code from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp) to filter the elements via a drop down.

```
function filterSelection(c, d) {
var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");

if (c == "all") c = "";
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
}
document.getElementById('formheader').innerHTML = d + ' Form(s)';
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
}
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
        arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
}
element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}
```

I added below in `filterSelection()` but it seems to only work once. Subsequent filters between `drop-down` and `input` don't work.

```
        var srcVal = document.getElementById('dirSearchKey').value;
    if (srcVal !== '') {
        document.getElementById('dirSearchKey').value = '';
        $("#searchBlock div[class^=filterDiv]").filter(function() {
            var value = '';
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Side note; in both of your snippets you are misusing the `filter()` method.  The filter method is intended to reduce an array to a subset.  In both of your cases, you are not doing this, only using it to iterate over the result stack.  If the only thing you want is iteration, use `each()` instead.

Comment: @Taplar, thanks for the suggestion.  I will research each() and redo the code.

Comment: It looks like you are not calling filterSelection() at all.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `filter()` with `.each()` and removed all the code I got from w3school (i.e. add/remove classes) and just used below

```
function filterSelection(d) {

if (d == "All") d = "";

$("#searchBlock div[class^=filterDiv]").each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("style");
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().indexOf(d) > -1);
});

document.getElementById('formheader').innerHTML = d;
```

}

When I was looking into `.each()` I looked into `.toggle()` as well and above is the result. Seems to work well after few tests.